# Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken azure deploy

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am facing strange issue, I want to integrate office 365 API's in my website. I'm following this git code sample [O365-ASPNETMVC-Start](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start). I follow all steps and successfully got emails and other data in my local machine, but when I deploy the same working app on Microsoft Azure, it throws the following exception **Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken** What this happening? My code runs perfectly in localhost but not on azure. Please help! I have checked my sql server connection string. there is no isue with connection string.

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that when I see this message I need to re-authenticate my Microsoft account.

I use multiple accounts on my workstation and the only time I see this message is when I'm signed out or signed into the wrong account.